# Stripe Payment 'client_reference_id'

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm intergrating with the Stripe Payment Gateway - the latest version of the API.

It's all working apart from the 'client_reference_id' does not get passed to either the webhook or the transaction (Does not appear in the log) - I need this to update the order in the database.

My code is:

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
                'amount' => 1011,
                'currency' => 'GBP',
                'name' => 'Purchase',
                'description' => 'test',
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'client_reference_id' => 'TEST1111223',
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
            'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
        ]);
```

According to the documentation this should be passed: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

Am I doing something wrong?

Someone else asked the same question but was not answered: [The "client_reference_id" argument is not passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247850/the-client-reference-id-argument-is-not-passed)

Answer (score 10):

It would make sense for the `customer.created` event to have the `client_reference_id`. However that is not the case! It does show up in the `checkout.session.completed` Event.

Below is the object detail

```
Stripe\Event Object
(
    [id] => evt_1KCO7....dffL4wc0
    [object] => event
    [api_version] => 2020-08-27
    [created] => 1640868753
    [data] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
        (
            [object] => Stripe\Checkout\Session Object
                (
                    [id] => cs_test_a1A....NhSTmvD
                    [object] => checkout.session
                    [after_expiration] => 
                    [allow_promotion_codes] => 
                    [amount_subtotal] => 15000
                    [amount_total] => 15000
                    [automatic_tax] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                        (
                            [enabled] => 
                            [status] => 
                        )

                    [billing_address_collection] => 
                    [cancel_url] => http://example.org/cancel
                    [client_reference_id] => 3181234
                    [consent] => 
                    [consent_collection] => 
                    [currency] => usd
                    [customer] => cus_Ks8...bT
                    [customer_details] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                        (
                            [email] => user@exmaple.org
                            [phone] => 
                            [tax_exempt] => none
                            [tax_ids] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [customer_email] => user@exmaple.org
                    [expires_at] => 1640955127
                    [livemode] => 
                    [locale] => 
                    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                        (
                        )

                    [mode] => payment
                    [payment_intent] => pi_3K...1p2sJ
                    [payment_method_options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [payment_method_types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => card
                        )

                    [payment_status] => paid
                    [phone_number_collection] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                        (
                            [enabled] => 
                        )

                    [recovered_from] => 
                    [setup_intent] => 
                    [shipping] => 
                    [shipping_address_collection] => 
                    [shipping_options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [shipping_rate] => 
                    [status] => complete
                    [submit_type] => 
                    [subscription] => 
                    [success_url] => http://exmaple.org/success
                    [total_details] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                        (
                            [amount_discount] => 0
                            [amount_shipping] => 0
                            [amount_tax] => 0
                        )

                    [url] => 
                )

        )

    [livemode] => 
    [pending_webhooks] => 2
    [request] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [idempotency_key] => 
        )

    [type] => checkout.session.completed
)
```

In the `customer.created` you do get the customer `email` if you passed it during checkout. You can also use that to connect it back to your customer without the need for the `client_reference_id`.  I check in both events and update the database with stripe customer id at the first successful opportunity.

Comment: I really really would not recommend to pass the email along and do the linking with that! There are customers out there that use different e-mails. For example the account e-mail is different to the one they used during the payment process. If you have a unique id on your side, us that! Otherwise you risk to generate yourself support cases.

Answer (score 0):

A unique string to reference the Checkout session. This can be a customer ID, a cart ID, or similar. It is included in the checkout.session.completed webhook and can be used to fulfill the purchase.

source https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout

Answer (score -5):

I did some digging and I think I know what's going on. Your client reference is alright, but you're likely not listening to both webhooks (If you are using stripe connect for example, you will get events on both hooks which can be deceiving).

I would use a truly unique ID for that client reference so that down to road you don't have mixed content. This v4 function works wonderously.

```
public static function v4() 
    {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',

        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }
```